# Custom List in C#

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, development, custom-list, custom-field-types

What I want to do is create a list with value checks and dynamic drop-down lists.

I know it is possible to create custom columns, but I need custom columns which are depending on each other.

For example, the table could look like this:

```
╔═════════════╦═════════════╦═══════════════════╦═════════════════════════════════════╗
║   SP Site   ║ Group Name  ║ Distribution List ║                Users                ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════╣
║ [Drop-Down] ║ [Drop-Down] ║ [foo@example.com] ║ [Multiple Selection with Drop-Down] ║
╚═════════════╩═════════════╩═══════════════════╩═════════════════════════════════════╝
```

While no `SP Site` is selected, the following fields need to be disabled.
The sites should be taken from the site collection and be dynamically fetched.
Once the site is selected, I want to fetch the groups which are present on the chosen site and present them in the drop-down list.

Afterwards you can enter a `Distribution List`, which will then be validated (needs to be a valid distribution list and not an e-mail address) and the users contained will be fetched for selection in the `[Users]` column.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can do this with JavaScript, but it works correctly only for site collections administrators or users that have at least Read access to all sites and groups in the site collection. You could also probably do this with C# and use elevated privileges and enable any user regardless of her/his permissions to view all sites/groups/etc. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is a concept called Cascading Dropdowns. There are some good techniques to achieve this effect. Start here. 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/cascading-of-lookup-dropdown-fields-on-sharepoint-2013-and-o/